# memcachedの有効キー総数

Tags: memcached

memcachedで有効キー（期限切れではない）の総数を取得したいと思っています。
ただし、プログラム側で有効キー数を全て抽出してその数を出すということは、1回/秒という頻度で行いたいこともありサーバ負荷がかかるのでやりたくありません。
statsのcurr_itemsで現在のデータ数は取得できますが、有効期限切れてる/切れていないの総数のようです。
どなたかサーバの負荷をあまりかけず有効キーの総数を取得する方法をご存知ないでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: memcachedの原理上、すべてのキーをスキャンしないと有効キー総数は分かりません。